# Can't add maximum and minimum date to DatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am trying to set maximum and minimum values to my Date Picker But it does not set this properties correctly.

I did this like below:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setLimitForDatePicker];
    birthdayTextField.inputView = _dateWithYearPicker;
}
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    _dateWithYearPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    _dateWithYearPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [_dateWithYearPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDateDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
-(void)setLimitForDatePicker
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:-16];
    NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    [comps setYear:-110];
    NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    _dateWithYearPicker.minimumDate = minDate;
    _dateWithYearPicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
}
```

After that when I launch application, and click on the birthdayTextField, the date picker appears to have not limits.

All your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is `_dateWithYearPicker` nil in `setLimitForDatePicker` ?

Comment: No, it's set from the awakeFromNib method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I switched the min and max date, the correct answer is :

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:-110]; //before it was 16
    NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    [comps setYear:-16]; // before it was 110
    NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    _dateWithYearPicker.minimumDate = minDate;
    _dateWithYearPicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
```